# Can not connect to TFS server

Tags: c#, tfs

I write program to connect TFS server and get Items from it.

```
 _tfsClient = new TFS2013Client(new Uri("http://server-tfs.domain.local:8080/tfs/"), _logger);




 public TFS2013Client(Uri tfsURI, ILogger logger)
     {
        _logger = logger;

        TfsURI = tfsURI;
        _configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(TfsURI);

        _server = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(TfsURI);
        Version = _server.GetService<VersionControlServer>();//exception here
       // Version = _server.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;
 }
```

And when i try to get `Version` object i get exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException' 
occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

    Additional information: TF31002: Unable to connect to this 
Team Foundation Server: http://server-tfs.domain.local:8080/tfs.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

404 error code.
```

I can connect with Visual Studio 2013 to TFS server. Server string is: `http://server-tfs:8080/tfs`. And it work fine.

When i set this addres to program- i have the same error.

Can you help me- why i can not connect to TFS via code?
May be i should authorize some way in code?

Thank you!

P.S. when i type this address into browser- go to TFS page.

P.P.S. The problem solved: i use this address: `http://server-tfs.domain.local:8080/tfs/collectionName`

Comment: Please either just delete the question or add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved: i use this address: `http://server-tfs.domain.local:8080/tfs/collectionName`

Comment: This worked for me,After adding my domain name after 'tfs/'